# Proceed (y/n)? in Python

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to uninstall my current version of keras and install an older version using:

```
!pip uninstall keras
!pip install keras==2.1.2
```

The return I get is :

```
Uninstalling Keras-2.1.2:
  Would remove:
    /home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.1.2.dist-info/*
    /home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Could I please get help with how to select yes?

Comment: pass `-y` flag. like `!pip install keras==2.1.2 -y`

Comment: @krishna I tried this, but  I get "no such option: -y"

Comment: maybe use `!pip -y install keras==2.1.2`

Comment: I've tried that too, but that still does not work

Comment: `echo "y" | !pip install keras==2.1.2`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't interact with shell commands after you launch them so you have to either pass the --yes flag:

```
!pip install keras==2.1.2 --yes
```

or you can execute your command outside of ipython (jupyter).

Answer (score 1):

On cent os I often must use

```
yes | bash cmd
```

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/yes.htm